# Powershell to transfer certificates to a new PC - how to determine if certificate is exportable

Tags: powershell, certificate

I'm using the following powershell to get a list of certificates including any archived ones so that I can easily transfer them to a new PC

```
$store=new-object 
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("My","CurrentUser")
$store.open("ReadOnly,IncludeArchived")
$privateCerts = $store.Certificates | Where-Object { $_.hasPrivateKey }
```

However, when I try and export them to pfx files using e.g.

```
$privateCerts| Foreach-Object { [system.IO.file]::WriteAllBytes("$($_.thumbprint)$($_.Subject).pfx", ($_.Export('PFX', 'password')) ) }
```

It throws exceptions for any that are not exportable.  Now I know that I cant export those but I'd like to just skip over them without having the script throw an error.  I can work around it by catching the exception but is there a way to determine if a certificate is exportable.

I found reference to x509keystorageflags which has an "exportable" bit I could check but I cant work out how to get that info for a certificate using powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Exportable` bit is set on the Private Key container itself, not directly on the certificate:

```
$privateCerts = $store.Certificates | Where-Object {$_.HasPrivateKey}
$Exportables  = $privateCerts | Where-Object {$_.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.Exportable}
```

I don't think this will work for other types than RSA-based keypairs

Comment: it will work for CAPI1-based providers, CAPI2 providers (CNG) are not supported in X509Certificate2 class.